# Корень в слове "лучезарный"

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор, корень-слова

**лучеза́рный**
Корень: **-лучезарн-**; окончание: **-ый** [Тихонов, 1996].
Происходит от слов "луч" и "заря".
[**Викисловарь**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Однокоренные слова: лучезарно, лучезарность.
В синониме этого слова [**светоза́рный**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) Тихонов выделяет два корня:
Корень: **-свет-**; интерфикс: **-о-**; корень: **-зар-**; суффикс: **-н**; окончание: **-ый**.

Никак не могу понять: почему же в "лучезарном" только один корень?
С чем это связано?

Answer (score 2):

**Морфема** ― минимальная **значимая** часть слова, которая не делится на более мелкие единицы того же уровня.

Лучезарный: Собственно русское слово, образованное путем сложения луч и заря и прибавления суффикса. [https://popular.academic.ru/1985/лучезарный](https://popular.academic.ru/1985/%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

**Луч/е/зар/н/ый.**

Выделенные  морфемы являются **минимально значимыми частями слова**, то есть **их значения понятны носителям языка.** Также про них можно сказать, что они регулярные и продуктивные ―  активно используются при словообразовании, в том числе  для образования новых слов.

Если этот разбор неверен, то **приведенное определение морфемы  неточно и нуждается в каких-то дополнениях.** Не имеет смысла сравнивать разборы в различных словарях, если у нас нет чёткого определения и каждая лингвистическая структура ориентируется на свое понимание морфемы.

Comment: Меня, собственно, интересовало: **почему** же один и тот же автор так по-разному эти слова "разобрал"? Думала, что есть какие-то особенности, которых я не знаю или не вижу. Вы считаете, что все-таки два корня?

Comment: Это я так считаю, но многие считают не так, и мне бы хотелось знать почему. Может быть,  кто-нибудь знает причину и даст ответ. Разумеется, лучезарный и светозарный  должны делиться на морфемы одинаково.